# Ellipse Circumference General Formula with Integration

Tags: integration, geometry, derivation-of-formulae

We are told ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse), for example) that the circumference or perimeter of an ellipse can only be approximated without the use of integration. How could we use integration to calculate the exact circumference of an ellipse with semi minor and major axes $a$ and $b$, respectively? Is there a generalized formula?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why we only have a approximation for every circumference for ellipse but not define a special formula for each ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73472/why-we-only-have-a-approximation-for-every-circumference-for-ellipse-but-not-def) It is the first link stackexchange shows as related.

Comment: Not really. I'm not looking for a computer algorithm solution.

Comment: There is no formula (in the sense you seem to want) for the perimeter of an ellipse. That's why elliptic integrals must be evaluated numerically. Here's another duplicate also suggested by stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041110/is-there-a-simpler-way-of-finding-the-circumference-of-an-ellipse?rq=1

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Comment: There are double/single series expansions for the elliptic integrals

Comment: The answer by J. M. on the linked dupe target shows the algorithm to compute the ellipse perimeter via the AGM (Arithmetic-Geometric Mean), which converges very quickly.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'll check it out, thanks.